# Get user email in Python-social-auth

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I have included this in my settings.py file:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email']
```

how do i access facebook user's email in pipeline.
I am using pythons-social-auth

I want to use user email address from facebook and check if a user with that email is already present or not.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: please check if its clear now

Answer (score 2):

You will have to customize a pipeline method or add a new one to the pipeline.

For example, you could customize a `create_user` method:

```
def create_user(strategy, details, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
    email = details.get('email', '')

    if UserClass.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        // do whatever you want

    if user:
        return {'is_new': False}

    fields = dict((name, kwargs.get(name) or details.get(name))
                  for name in strategy.setting('USER_FIELDS',
                                               USER_FIELDS))
    if not fields:
        return

    return {
        'is_new': True,
        'user': strategy.create_user(**fields)
    }
```

then in your settings file, indicate a path to this method:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'path.to.your.custom.create_user',    // indicate the path here
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details'
)
```

hope this helps

**UPDATE:**

If you are not getting `email` in the `details` parameter, try this:

Print the `response` variable in `social_details` method of pipeline:

```
def social_details(backend, details, response, *args, **kwargs):
    print response
    return {'details': dict(backend.get_user_details(response),
                            **details)}
```

see in the logs if response contains `email`. If it does contain `email`, it means that `email` is just not being included in the `details` parameter in `details` variable.

If not, is `SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email']` working? I mean, is Facebook asking you to grant this scope when you login?

If yes, grant it. If no, try to delete your app from facebook, and register again. It sometimes happens.

Comment: thanks, but the problem is, i am not getting email in detail data

Comment: really? delete app from fb?

Answer (score 0):

This may be an old question but the answer is import to lots of people. So here we go.

First you grant the `scope`, then you `harvest` the data. So your django `settings.py` file needs these two settings (in addition to `key` and `secret`)

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email']
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = {
  'locale': 'en',
  'fields': 'id, name, email,
}
```

Be aware that during authentication the user may decide to not supply the email even though you've asked for it. So instead of getting email with `response['email']` use `response.get('email', None)`. Then handle the case where email is not provided.